# Docker Cannot assign requested address on .NET app with Selenium

Tags: c#, .net, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to make a Web Scraper as a .NET project and I'm required to run the app on a Docker container using Linux on WSL2. The problem is that this app uses Selenium Webdriver and every time i try to run the app on Visual Studio 2022 i get the following error

```
Cannot assign requested address [::1]:39307 (localhost:39307)
./chromedriver: error while loading shared libraries: libgobject-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

My dockerfile is the following

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj", "ConsoleApp1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/ConsoleApp1"
RUN sudo apt-get install -y libgbm-dev
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y  google-chrome-stable
RUN dotnet build "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "ConsoleApp1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ConsoleApp1.dll"]
```

And the code that produces the error is this one

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace IntroSelenium
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("headless");
            chromeOptions.AddArguments("--verbose");
            using (ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(".", chromeOptions))
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it

Comment: You may need additional libraries in order to make selenium work. Check [this](https://tecadmin.net/setup-selenium-with-chromedriver-on-debian/) out.

Comment: To me it sounds like you're running something that want to start listening on port 39307, but it can't. Probably because the port is taken by something else. Probably another running or stopped instance of the container? How do you start your container?

Comment: @HansKilian i am starting the container directly from Visual Studio 2022, if i remove "ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(".", chromeOptions)" the containers works fine.

Comment: If you have Docker Desktop, you should be able to see any active containers using port 39307 and remove them before starting a new one.